# Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/merge'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs

I have a React project, where I am using Babel and Webpack.

In one the files, I have the following `require` statement:

```
var merge = require('react/lib/merge');
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/stores/CountryStore.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/merge'
```

Is there another way of requiring the component?

Answer (score 2):

'react/lib/merge'  is deprecated.

try

```
npm install merge
```

and instead of

```
var merge = require('react/lib/merge');
```

use

```
var merge = require('merge');
```